# Is this minimal complete system?

Tags: propositional-calculus

In propositional logic, I know that this natural deduction system is complete:

Rules of inference: MP, Abs, Simp, Add

Rules of replacement: DM, Com, Assoc, Dist, DN, Impl, Equiv

But I want to know: is this minimal? i.e., is it still complete if one of these rules is omitted?